# Laravel 5 Sync Two or More Models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, synchronization

I'm still learning Laravel and I'm stuck in this current problem where I can't sync two models in a pivot table.

This is in my `MenuGroup Model` (a pivot table)

```
public function menus_group(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Menus\MenusGroup');
}
public function menu(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Menus\Menu');
}
```

BTW, MenuGroup Model has 3 columns, `menu_id`, `menu_groups_id` and `order`.

I have other models as well, Menu and MenusGroup. What I wanted is to sync this in one of my controllers. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you have a model for a pivot table? That kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: that was how it was set up by default by my coworker.. but i think it's still okay to use it that way?

Comment: If it works, it works... :) but unless it causes a major rewrite of your application, you may want to look into proper pivot table handling.

Comment: I think there's a reason why he set it up like that. But yeah it works.. now what I don't know is how to sync them up, I only know how when it is set up with just 2 tables..

Comment: I can use the create method for this model to solve this problem.. the only thing I'm worried are the duplicates.. and I think it's not the Laravel way of doing things.. lol.

Answer (score 0):

To use Eloquent relationship with pivot table you have the belongsToMany method:

```
public function menus_group(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Menus\MenusGroup');
}
public function menu(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Menus\Menu');
}
```

Also you may override some convention defaults

```
$this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Menus\Menu', 'pivot_table_name', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```